# Tmux keeps changing window

Tags: tmux

I'm discovering Tmux, and I'm facing an annoying problem:

When i switch window in Tmux with ctrl + arrow, Tmux keeps the focus on my keyboard.

here is an example of what it does: when i do `ctrl + B [left arrow] [upper arrow]`, instead of going to the left window (terminal) and display my previous command, Tmux go to the left window, and then, to the upper window.

Anyone know any way to lose the focus after one command? I did not found any answers atm

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the `repeat-time` option and the `-r` flag to the `bind-key` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your ~/.tmux.conf

```
# command delay, don't want that, make it short
set -g escape-time 10

# Allow the arrow key to be used immediately after changing windows
set-option -g repeat-time 0
```